# How to iterate class variables in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, interface

I am using typescript and I had this class where I need to iterate the values in it.

```
export default class ModelShadow {
    story: Story[] = [];
    name: string = '';
}

export interface Story {
    title: Title[];
    header: Title[];
}

export interface Title {
    name: string;
    description: string;
}

export const Text1 = ({index}) => {
    <div>
       <input name='story.{index}.name'/>
    </div>
    <div>
       <input name='story.{index}.description'/>
    </div> 
    <button onClick={function that deletes the array depends on the index > delete </button> 


export const Text2 = ({index}) => {
        <div>
           <input name='header.{index}.name'/>
        </div>
        <div>
           <input name='header.{index}.description'/>
        </div> 
          <button onClick={function that deletes the array depends on the index > delete </button>
```

I had a Select that adds the Text above to an array and I want to eliminate the null values upon submit. Because every I choose Text1 the index is 0 and add another Text2, the index is 1 and so on so forth.

The result was like this:

```
  story:
     header: 0: { name: 'test', description: 'test' }
             1: null
             2: { name: 'test', description: 'test' }
     title: 0: null
            1: { name: test', description: 'test' }
```

It should be like this,

```
 header: 0: { name: 'test', description: 'test' }
         1: { name: 'test', description: 'test' }
 title:  0: { name: test', description: 'test' }
```

Thank so much.

Comment: There is honestly a lot that's wrong here.  For example the `{index}` in your input names is going to be the literal string `"{index}"`, not the actual `index` variable.  Can you provide a more complete code on CodeSandbox?  I don't see anywhere here that you are iterating over properties so I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve or what you are trying to fix.

Comment: You need to either join strings with the `+` operator or use template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: `Text1` and `Text2` can definitely be combined into one generalized component where the differences in behavior can be controlled via props.